# iPhone simulator only shows title bar

Tags: ios, xcode

after deleting installed apps on my iPhone simulator, my current app only shows the title bar from the first view while running on the simulator. Any idea what had happened?

Comment: You've stumbled into the support for the new iPen one-line display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top menu click iOS Simulator - > Reset content and settings.
Then, reinstall the app and have fun.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have done what you have said and nothing has changed.

Comment: I have now noticed that every time I created a new project, the project file *.app under the Project Group, is always showed in red color.???